# Map Network drives reading from csv VBS

Tags: vbscript

Should work as
User logs in, runs a vbs logon script added at login script that runs through the csv and maps only where the username is the same as the logged on user.

I have tried

```
on error resume next
strCSV = "c:\name.csv"
$network = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network
$network.MapNetworkDrive($Driveletter, $share, $username)
```

where csv contains

```
User,Driveletter,share
jack,Y:, S:,"\\server\Lincoln", "\\server\share"
Tim,Z:,"\\Server\Google"
Victor,U:, V:, X:,"\\server\home","\\server\share","\\server\share"
```

do not work can anyone help?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error nothing happens

Comment: Well no, that'll be because `on error resume next` ignores errors.  Try running the script with that commented out and see what errors you get.

Comment: let me try do you think its a good idea it may take long time right? to read csv rows and map

Comment: line:2 char:1 invalid character code:800A0408

Comment: Lines 3 and 4 are not vbscript, it's PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

1. You never read the csv-file. In VBScript you would need to read the file line by line etc. using a `FileSystemObject`. If you could use Powershell this would be done with `$SomeVarName = Import-CSV -Path "c:\name.csv"`
2. You're mixing VBScript (line 1+2) and PowerShell (3+4).
3. The CSV-file is invalid. You have more columns in the value-rows(line 2+) than you have in your header.

A valid CSV-file for this would be:

```
User,Driveletter,share
jack,Y:,"\\server\Lincoln"
jack,S:,"\\server\share"
Tim,Z:,"\\Server\Google"
Victor,U:,"\\server\home"
Victor,V:,"\\server\share"
Victor,X:,"\\server\share"
```